# Paths in graphs as a vector space or matroid

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, enumerative-combinatorics, matroid-theory

If I have a simple graph $G$, and what to count the number of simple paths between two distinct vertices, can the paths be seen as independent sets of a vector space, or even somehow, a matroid? I have seen for example path matroids, and gammoids, and some connections to the cycle matroid, since multiple paths between two points can be united to form cycles.

If I can, in fact, set this problem up as a vector space or matroid, is there some general theory for counting the number of subspaces? In this case, they would be the paths which differ on at least one edge.

Comment: I can’t see how this could work.. in a matroid, a subset of an independent set is independent, but there is no obvious general way in which to make paths behave like this.

Comment: What about as a vector space. A basis of the space would a set of paths which can be added together to form the union of paths, say of k-hops for a set value of k. There would then be a number of bases to choose from.

Comment: I mean, the edge space is a vector space over GF(2), and (say directed) paths are unions of edges tip to tail.